# What is the scope of outer class that has an inner lambda expression

Tags: class, kotlin, lambda, scope, binding

I apologize for the bad title because i have difficult to find the correct way to describe my issue.
So i will try to achieve it by a code:

```
    class CompetitionDetailsViewHolder() : RecyclerViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(competitionDetailsData: CompetitionDetailsData) {
            binding.apply {
                val topItemSections = sectionsMap?.get(true)?.take(2) ?: emptyList()
                setSectionVisibility(topItemSections) {.....}
                ....
                ....
            }
        }
        
         private fun setSectionVisibility(
            sections: List<GeneralCompetitionDetailsSection>,
            block: (sections: List<GeneralCompetitionDetailsSection>, isVisible: Boolean) -> Unit) 
        {
            block(sections, sections.isNotEmpty())
        }
}
```

I can't understand how the code: **setSectionVisibility(topItemSections) {.....}** works?
The issue i see here is:
**binding.apply** gets a lambda expression. inside the lambda expression the keyword **this** refers to **binding** object, therefore i can't understand how the method **setSectionVisibility** which belongs to  **CompetitionDetailsViewHolder** class can be called by implicit this (which as i already say refers to **binding** object)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> inside the lambda expression the keyword `this` refers to binding object,

Yes

> therefore i can't understand how the method `setSectionVisibility` which belongs to `CompetitionDetailsViewHolder` class can be called by implicit `this`

"Implicit this" is exactly the key here. You are not saying `this.setSectionVisibility`, just `setSectionVisibility` without any qualifications. This makes all the difference.

When resolving calls, calls with an explicit receiver and calls with an implicit receiver are handled differently, as specified in the two different sections in the language spec: [calls with an explicit receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#call-with-an-explicit-receiver), [calls with an implicit receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#call-without-an-explicit-receiver).

Here is a quote from the latter section, describing how it works:

> For an identifier named `f` the following sets are analyzed (in the
> given order):
>
> 1. Local non-extension callables named f in the current scope and its upwards-linked scopes, ordered by the size of the scope (smallest
>    first), excluding the package scope;
> 2. [...]
>
> When analyzing these sets, the first set which contains any callable
> with the corresponding name and conforming types is picked for c-level
> partition, which gives us the resulting overload candidate set.

As you can see, it tries to find methods named `setSectionVisibility` "in the current scope *and its upwards-linked scopes*". The scope of the `CompetitionDetailsViewHolder` class is an upwards-linked scope of the scope of the `apply` lambda, and that is where it will find `setSectionVisibility`.

Note that if there is also a method called `setSectionVisibility` with the same signature on the binding object, then that method will be called instead, not `CompetitionDetailsViewHolder.setSectionVisibility`.

On the other hand, assuming `binding` does not have an accessible method called `setSectionVisibility`, `this.setSectionVisibility` fails to compile because in the "call with explicit receiver" section it is specified that:

> A call of callable `f` with an explicit receiver `e` is correct if at
> least one of the following holds:
>
> 1. `f` is an accessible member callable of the classifier type `type(e)` or any of its supertypes;
> 2. `f` is an accessible extension callable of the classifier type `type(e)` or any of its supertypes, including top-level, local and
>    imported extensions.
> 3. `f` is an accessible static member callable of the classifier type `e`.

Comment: i must admit that i tried to read from the links you have sent me and i didn't understand nothing. If you can clarify a little bit what is written there i will be glad. But more important, it in the code was written **this. setSectionVisibility** then code won't work?

Comment: @Eitanos30 That is correct, yes, unless `binding` also has a method called `setSectionVisibility`, in which case that will be called instead. I've also tried to make it clearer.

Comment: @Eitanos30 I've tried to remove some parts that are not too relevant to the situation in your question, and also added a quote from the explicit receiver section. I agree that language specs are quite challenging to read, if this is your first time reading one. If you just want a dumbed down but a little imprecise explanation - `setSectionVisibility` is resolved differently than how you'd expected, *because the spec says so*. The compiler looks at all the scopes and receivers available. You expected the behaviour for `this.setSectionVisibility`, where only the type of `this` matters.

Comment: I'm just disappointed not to understand the spec :(
I'm accepting your answer. Can you please explain the following sentence:
"where only the type of this matters"?

Comment: @Eitanos30 I mean, whether `this.setSectionVisibility` is valid depends on the type of `this` only (and in this case is the `binding`'s type) - if the type of `this` has `setSectionVisibility` (extension or not) then it is valid, otherwise it is not. On the other hand,  in the case of `setSectionVisibility`,  parent scopes are searched to see if they contain anything called `setSectionVisibility`, as well as (I've omitted this from the quote) the overload resolution sets for each implicit receiver, treated as an explicit receiver.